# When hovering over <nav> link, website randomly changes the hover background size

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

While working on my website, I have decided to incorporate PHP just to play around with. I figure I'm paying for it in hosting (sort of), so might as well use it. The problem I am having is when I hover over a link in the nav bar I have made, the hover "decoration" that I am using changes the hover background height. Problem is, it does it on every page BUT not all the time. Seems random. For some reason it seems to be doing it more on my about page but I have seen it do it on others. I haven't made any changes to the others to make them stop nor any changes to the about to make it start more.

The site in question http://www.journeytomyoasis.com

<del>Since I can't post images yet, here is a link to a screenshot</del>

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [journeytomyoasis.com](http://journeytomyoasis.com/images/common/hover_error.png))</sub>

Code that is in the top of about page

```
<?php $page_title = "About | Journey to my Oasis"; ?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=15681725508";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<?php include("includes/header.php");?>
<?php include("includes/navigation.php");?>
```

code in the navigation.php

```
<!-- Begin Navigation -->
<nav>
    <div id="nav_container">
        <div id="menu"> 
            <a href="http://www.journeytomyoasis.com/about.php">ABOUT</a>  
            <a href="http://www.journeytomyoasis.com/blog">BLOG</a> 
            <a href="http://www.journeytomyoasis.com/portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a href="http://www.journeytomyoasis.com/blog/journey/">JOURNEY</a>
            <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20161001170100/http://journeytomyoasis.com/">HOME</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--END Navigation-->
```

At the top of the about page I included the Facebook code that I am using so that you all know it is there in case you all might think that is it. I have poured over the code a lot but I cant see an error. The fact that it is the same php file used on all pages and every page has had issue at least once but not always confuses me.

I have tested on Firefox and IE 10

Thank you all.

Comment: just add #menu a {height: 17px !important;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at around line 110 of `structure.css`:

```
#menu a:hover {
    background: #c2d4ec;
    height: 41;
    color: white;
}
```

You're explicitly setting the height of the menu items to `41px` (browsers will generally assume pixels if you don't specify a unit, though technically it's not allowed) on hover. Remove that and they won't change size.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I did change that, however, it is still doing it.

Comment: You meant remove the whole line. Makes sense. I just added the px. Then I re-read your answer. Thank you so much.

Thank you for looking at the CSS. Didn't feel I should copy the whole thing. I guess I could have copied the nav part alone. up next comes cleaning my code.